# HttpModule Deployment aka HttpModule Installer

Tags: deployment, installation, httpmodule

I have been working on a project which partially consists of a HttpModule.  I would like to make setup of this HttpModule as simple as possible for admins.  Thus, I am seeking any opinion or suggestion of technology/method as to the easiest method of deployment for this HttpModule.

If viewing the code is helpful, it can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/opendms-dot-net/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FHttpModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your module is supposed to integrate with an existing web application, the simplest thing would probably be to just distribute the assembly and an example web.config, in a zip file. If your project is supposed to be installed as a stand-alone web application, you could create a ["Web Setup Project"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kzx145%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent, I was planning on that for hooking into an existing web application.  Now, a "Web Setup Project" only works with IIS correct?  I'm planning on targeting *nix with mono as well as IIS.  In view of that information would you suggest just going with a .zip for a full website setup also?